# Android RelativeLayout layout_toLeftOf doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc">

     <!-- LEFT -->
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/lp" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="50px" 
        android:layout_height="100px" 
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/lp"
        android:id="@+id/lc" />        
    <!-- END LEFT -->

    <!-- RIGHT -->
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="300px"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/rp" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="50px" 
        android:layout_height="100px" 
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/rp"
        android:id="@+id/rc" />        
    <!-- END LEFT -->    
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

What I expect is:

[image]

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The answer below is just a workaround,but I want to know why your code doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer to get it working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc">

     <!-- LEFT -->
    <View
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/lp" />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="50dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/lp"
        android:id="@+id/lc" />        
    <!-- END LEFT -->

    <!-- RIGHT -->
    <View
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/rp" />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="50dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/rp"
        android:id="@+id/rc" />        
    <!-- END LEFT -->    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Do not use px. Use dip/dp (independent pixels). Also to create your coloured blocks you only need a View, however it depends what is going in them.

Read this tutorial I found it really useful for layouts - http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/5/

Answer (score 0):

from **android:layout_toLeftOf**  definition:
Positions the right edge of this view to the left of the given anchor view ID. **Accommodates right margin** of this view and left margin of anchor view.

So, the magic is put the dummy View without margin:

```
  <View 
    android:id="@+id/ltEdge"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lp"        
      />

  <View
    android:layout_width="50px" 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ltEdge"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/lp"
    android:id="@+id/lc" />
```